# Is It possible to use the same SYMMETRIC-KEY(SQL Server Column-level Encryption) among serveral database on a sql server instance?

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I build two different system (Sales System and Finance System) which has its own database on the same SQL Server instace.  
The Bank_AccountNO field(varbinary data type) must be cipher on those two system. But the Bank_AccountNO was input only on Sales System, then the bank account NO data was sync to Finance System automatically by sql trigger.
When I create MASTER KEY , I found I must select an database name first.It means the SYMMETRIC KEY also belong to some particular database I just selected.
So is it possible to use the same SYMMETRIC-KEY(SQL Server Column-level Encryption) among serveral database located on one same sqlserver instance?
Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indirectly. You can create the same key in each database by providing the same values for `key_source` and `identity_value` when issuing the `create symmetric key` statement.

Comment: It works!  Thanks a lot  for solving my problem.